# Bootstrap default navbar dropdown has transparent background in collapse mode?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the default bootstrap navbar, and I am having issues when the navbar is in collapse mode.  When I click the dropdown button the navbar drops down, but the background of the drop down is transparent (or less likely, the same color as the body).  What is going on here? I've tried two different navbars, and the same thing happens.  The last one I used was from here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

And even if you don't the answer to the above, how could I select the navbar dropdown with CSS? so I could try a few more things to get it right.

You can view the problem's source at mainevillefamilyphysicians.com .  Excuse the poor positioning of all the other elements on the page at small page sizes that has been fixed but not pushed to to the host.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `navbar-default` to the class on the `ul` of the menu.  That will give you the default color for your menu background.  You could also use `navbar-inverse` or define your own class in your css and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're assigning the height for the .navbar in your style.css file to 100px , so it'll show the 100px of it colored, and the remaining space will be transparent.
Try making it like that in your style.css:

```
.navbar{
height:100%;
}
```